# this.localMethod() Inspection/Extraction in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My company's coding standards dictate that when invoking local methods, we have to prefix the call with `this`.

Is there an inspection I can enable in Intellij so that places where `localMethod()` are used instead of `this.localMethod()` are highlighted?

In addition to this, I frequently use the *extract method* function that Intellij offers, however the method call that gets left behind is `localMethod()` rather than `this.localMethod()`, is there a way I can alter the code that is inserted when using this extraction to include `this` automatically?

Comment: I think none of those are available on idea. Why don't you just replace all 'localMethod()' with 'this.localMethod()' and then replace all 'this.this' with 'this'?

Comment: Rather than finding a way to make myself remember to do that every time I write new code, I might as well try and remember to write this.localMethod() in the first place. Also, in addition to when writing my own code, I want to be able to see the mistake when I'm peer reviewing other people's code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such an inspection. It's called "Instance method call not qualified with 'this".

I don't think there's an option for "Extract method" to always add 'this' qualifiers.

Comment: Thanks, this gets me at least half way there, so I can at least see when I've missed it